# Question about notation and meaning in the expression of limit of a derivative

Tags: derivatives, definition

I am sure this is a trivial matter but I can't seem to get an answer by myself and tried searching it and arrived at nothing.

My question is if these expressions are equal.

$$\lim_{x\to{x_0}}f^{'}(x)=\lim_{x\to{x_0}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

My confusion was in that I know that the one in the right **is** the definition of the derivative in $x_0$  and I'm thinking that the left one is the limit of the derivative **function**.

I hope I made myself understandable

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit on the left need not exist - a differentiable function can have a discontinuous derivative. To show this, integrate a suitable badly behaved function to get a differentiable $f$ with a badly behaved derivative.

Comment: A little side note I'd like to ask if possible, if the limit on the left-hand side exists and it's real for example $(L)$, can I prove somehow that $f^{'}(x_0)=L$, or does it only imply that it tends to $(L)$ without being the value at $f^{'}(x_{0})=L$

Comment: @Ramirogenta One thing I didn't say also is that the original function might only be differentiable at a single point. If the derivative exists and is continuous in an interval about $x_0$ then the bad behaviour goes away. Thinking about any function, it is continuity which secures that the limit of the function as it approaches a point is the value of the function at that point. Bringing in the derivative obscures that simple point. One thing to remember is that differentiating a real-valued function can lead to a worse-behaved function than you started with.

Comment: To extend the above comment, that is why smooth functions can be useful - ones which are differentiable as many times as you like. And having learned the pathologies of real-valued functions, the fact that differentiable functions of a single complex variable are analytic (differentiable as many times as you like) is a real surprise. So there is plenty to learn and quite a lot of surprises and beauty. And if you keep thinking in this kind of a way, you will soon get a feel of how the pieces all fit together.